# Inner product preserving means $A^TA=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure why the two definitions of orthogonality are equivalent.

How does $A$ preserving inner product mean $A^TA=I$ (and the converse)?

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

In a real vector space $V$, inner product preserving, by definition means that, $\forall x,y\in V$: 
$$
<x,y>=<Ax, Ay>=<x, A^TAy> \Rightarrow \\ \\  <x,y>-<x, A^TAy>=<x, y-A^TAy>=0 \Rightarrow \\ \\ 
y-A^TAy=0 \Rightarrow y=A^TAy, \forall y\in V \Rightarrow \\ \\
A^TA=I
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$<Ax, Ay>= <x, A^T Ay>$$

Therefore 
$$<x,y>=<Ax, Ay> \Leftrightarrow <x,y>=<x, A^TAy>\Leftrightarrow <x,y- A^TAy>=0$$

A you want this for all $x,y$, setting $x=y-A^TAy$ you get that this is equivalent to 
$$y-A^TAy=0 \Leftrightarrow y= A^TAy \forall y$$

Comment: Isn't it the adjoint and not the transpose though?

Comment: @user378024 $<x,y>=x^Ty$ which means that $<Ax,Ay>=(Ax)^TAy=x^TA^TAY$.